# I can't generate rails project, Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - connect(2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm using OS X 10.7, ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249), and rails 3.2.1, rubygems 1.8.24 :

```
➜  code  ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]
➜  code  gem list | grep rails 
rails (3.2.1, 3.2.0, 3.1.0, 3.0.5)
➜  code  gem list | grep gem   
rubygems-update (1.8.24)
```

As for the sources of gem :

```
➜  code  gem sources                                                     
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***
http://gems.rubyforge.org
http://gems.github.com
http://gems.github.com
http://gems.github.com
http://production.s3.rubygems.org
http://production.s3.rubygems.org.s3.amazonaws.com/
http://rubygems.org/
```

Now I'm trying to create a rails project :

```
➜  code  rails new blogging -d mysql
Using #!/usr/bin/ruby begin require 'hirb' # sudo gem install cldwalker-hirb --source http://gems.github.com Hirb.enable rescue LoadError end def change_log(stream) ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(stream) ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections! end def show_log change_log(STDOUT) end def hide_log change_log(nil) end from /Users/Apple/.railsrc
      create  
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/images/rails.png
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/mailers
      create  app/models
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/mailers/.gitkeep
      create  app/models/.gitkeep
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  doc
      create  doc/README_FOR_APP
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.gitkeep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.gitkeep
      create  log
      create  log/.gitkeep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/index.html
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  script
      create  script/rails
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.gitkeep
      create  test/functional
      create  test/functional/.gitkeep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.gitkeep
      create  test/unit
      create  test/unit/.gitkeep
      create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/plugins
      create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
         run  bundle install
Enter your password to install the bundled RubyGems to your system: 
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - connect(2) (https://rubygems.org/gems/i18n-0.6.0.gem)
An error occured while installing i18n (0.6.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install i18n -v '0.6.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I installed i18n manually but still getting the same error, I added new resources to the gem and with no luck .

Any help would be highly appreciated .

Thanks in advance 
Eqbal

Comment: is there any chance it is a DNS issue and if yes wht am I supposed to do to make sure ?

Comment: Run `wget https://rubygems.org/gems/i18n-0.6.0.gem`. Or substitute `wget` for `curl`. Or install either one to test your connection and/or DNS. Or use `nslookup rubygems.org` to check just the DNS. However you got a timeout error, which does not seem like a DNS problem.

Comment: can u check out the results and tell me what you think ? https://gist.github.com/4da0269e868b693907c9 , thanks Casper

Comment: Are you behind some sort of home router or firewall or something? I tried the exact same rubygems server as you, and it connected no problem. It almost looks like your port 443 (https) is being blocked for some reason. Try `telnet rubygems.org 443` and see if it connects, if not you're having firewall/router issues.

Comment: Ur absolutely right here, it seems that the firewall is blocking https, just changed the conf there and things r working now , cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Rails 3.2 is the last version that supports ruby 1.8, and 1.9.2 or 1.9.3 are recommended.

But to your question: it looks like DNS issue. Can you reach rubygems.org directly via `curl`/`wget` or your browser (if it's normal computer)?

You could also run `traceroute rubygems.org` and see where connection fails (I'm not quite sure if on OS X is traceroute or tracert)

My last idea would be to run `ping rubygems.org` and try running traceroute to the returned IP

Comment: Thanks for your willing to help here, I thought the same as for the regards of the DNS, but I can ping/wget rubygems.org , check this out please https://gist.github.com/4da0269e868b693907c9 , any other ideas ?

Comment: I wanted to post next idea, but I see that problem is solved. But you definitely have to take a look at your firewall/router because it will generate a lot of issues in future.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error can happen if your internet connection is kind of dodgy.

I found that using a publicly available wifi gave me this error, but running bundle worked when I tethered from my smartphone.